# How to pass html into JQuery and find a single element and replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am looking at being able to pass a piece of html into a for loop, but I want to use the html as a selector and find classes and elements inside it, and replace the html.

HTML

```
        <div class="item sub-item">
             <div class="row">
                <p class="blog-single-main-content"></p>
             </div>
        </div>
```

JQuery

```
         //This menthod grabs the entire html including the parent I am selecting
         var getHtml =  $('#blog .sub-item').wrap('<p/>').parent().html();

         //Amount of Objects being passed back from my AJAX query
         var amount = Object.keys(results).length;

            setTimeout(function(){
               for(i = 0; i < amount; i++){

                  //Take all of the html I have selected, find the class inside it and replace the html
                  $(getHtml).find(".blog-single-main-content").html("New 
                  html");

                  //Take the new amended html and append it to my main div
                  $('#main-blog-list').append(getHtml);
               }
            },1000)
```

As I want to add in a div for how every many object keys are returned from AJAX, I dont want to have to write an append function and pass a large chunk of html. Instead I would like to select all of the html first and change the elements based on my loop and append it each time with the new data.

I want to take the `.sub-item` div and copy it, so that I can append it onto my main div. I'm running it in a for loop, and I want to pass the whole HTML code into jquery, find the `.blog-single-main-content` element and replace the html inside of it and append the whole html back into a parent div, multiple times.

The easy way for me to achieve this would be to just say

```
 for(i = 0; i < amount; i++){
 $('body').append("<div class='item sub-item'><div class='row'><p 
 class='blog-single-main-content'>"+'This is loop' + i +"</p></div></div>");
 }
```

But I want to pass in a large amount of html, so that way is not very practical.

What is the best way to achieve this?

OUTPUT

```
 $(getHtml).find(".blog-single-main-content").html('New html');
 $('#main-blog-list').append(getHtml);
```

current appends the original html inside the `.blog-single-main-content` element instead of replacing it with `New Html` first before appending.

Comment: What is the output of your code? Does it work? Why do you need a `settimeout`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that is representative of your issue. Really not clear what you are asking or where you need help